# Source folder not showing in eclipse

Tags: eclipse, gradle

In my gradle project I have the following source folder structure:

```
src/main/java
src/main/resources
src/test/java
src/test/resources
src/test/bdd/design/java
src/test/bdd/design/resources
src/test/bdd/interaction/java
src/test/bdd/interaction/resources
```

But when I import my project only the following packages show up in project explorer:

```
src/main/java
src/main/resources
src/test/java
src/test/resources
```

How do I make the other packages also appear by default in project explorer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on how they are being used. If you want to share the same JavaCompile task as the rest of the tests then you can add extra java/resource dirs to the "test" sourceSet.

```
sourceSets.test {
    java {
        srcDir 'src/test/bdd/design/java'
        srcDir 'src/test/bdd/interaction/java'
    }
    resources {
       srcDir 'src/test/bdd/design/resources'
       srcDir 'src/test/bdd/interaction/resources'
    }
}
```

If you want separate compile and test tasks with their own classpaths you'll want separate source sets.

```
sourceSets.create('bddDesign') 
sourceSets.create('bddInteraction') 
sourceSets.bddDesign {
    java.srcDir 'src/test/bdd/design/java' 
    resources.srcDir 'src/test/bdd/design/resources'
}
sourceSets.bddInteraction {
    java.srcDir 'src/test/bdd/interaction/java'
    resources.srcDir 'src/test/bdd/interaction/resources'
}
```

For the second option it's likely you will create at least one [Configuration](https://docs.gradle.org/current/javadoc/org/gradle/api/artifacts/Configuration.html) for each source set so that each can have an independent classpath

Eg

```
configurations {
   bddDesignCompile {
       extendsFrom configurations.javaCompile
   } 
} 
sourceSets.bddDesign.java {
    compileClasspath = files(configurations.bddDesignCompile, sourceSets.main.output)
} 
dependencies {
    bddDesignCompile 'com:foo:1.2.3'
}
```

For extra inspiration see [JavaFlavoursExtension.groovy](https://github.com/uklance/gradle-java-flavours/blob/master/src/main/groovy/com/lazan/javaflavours/JavaFlavoursExtension.groovy)